# How do I create a thumbnail for each video after uploading multiple selected videos

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a thumbnail preview of several video files (mp4.3gp) of dropzone plugin.

And I want to create a thumbnail of each video selected at the input (if there are 5 videos, create 5 thumbnails). I've seen many implementations, but none with multiple contexts.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
// added file video in dropzone plugin
myDropzone.on('addedfile', function(origFile) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    var origFileIndex = myDropzone.files.indexOf(origFile);// FileList object
    myDropzone.files[origFileIndex].status = Dropzone.ADDED;
    var blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: origFile.type});
    console.log(blob)
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var video = document.createElement('video');//added now
    var timeupdate = function() {
      if (snapImage()) {
        video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
        video.pause();
      }
    };
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
      if (snapImage()) {
        video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
      }
    });
    // Only process video files
    if (!origFile.type.match(/mp4|MP4/)) {
      myDropzone.enqueueFile(origFile);
      return;
    }
    var snapImage = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var arrText = new Array();
      var  image = canvas.toDataURL();
      var success = image.length > 100000;
      if (success) {
      var img = document.getElementsByClassName('imgthumbnail');
      var l = img.length;
      $.each(img,function(){
        arrText.push(image);
      });
      for(var i=0; i < l; i++){
        var t = img[i];
          t.src = arrText[i];// add `src image` 
      }
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
      return success;
    };
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
    video.preload = 'metadata';
    video.src = url;
    // Load video in Safari / IE11
    video.muted = true;
    video.playsInline = true;
    video.play();
  }, false);
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(origFile);
});
```

After uploading multiple video files, a thumbnail of the video is shared for each video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attaching src to variable t you forgot to add it to DOM. While preview was captured, it was not displayed anywhere. And **img** element is required to use "src" attribute (src won't work on div).

You could create **img** element and append it to .imgthumbnail div:

```
$('<img>', {'src': arrText[i]}).appendTo('.imgthumbnail');
```

Alternatively, you could pass thumbnail to Dropzone and display it in uploaded file block:

```
myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", origFile, arrText[i]);
```

In this case you'll probably want to make some style adjustments to correctly fit thumbnail in Dropzone block.

To process 3gp files too, don't forget to add 3gp extensions to type.match selector.